# "iron::Modifier<Response> is not implemented" while trying to set content-type on response using iron and mime

Tags: rust, mime, iron

I am trying to run the examples from the book *Programming Rust* published by O'Reilly and I am stuck at making the following code compile successfully:

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "gcd-online"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Jignesh Gohel <abc@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
iron = "0.6.0"
mime = "0.3.12"
router = "0.6.0"
urlencoded = "0.6.0"
```

**/src/main.rs**

```
extern crate iron;
extern crate mime;

use iron::prelude::*;
use iron::status;

fn main() {
    println!("Serving on http://localhost:3000...");
    Iron::new(get_form).http("localhost:3000").unwrap();
}


fn get_form(_request: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let mut response = Response::new();

    response.set_mut(status::Ok);
    response.set_mut(mime::TEXT_HTML_UTF_8);
    response.set_mut(r#"
        <title>GCD Calculator</title>
        <form action="/gcd" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="n" />
            <input type="text" name="m" />
            <button type="submit">Compute GCD</button>
        </form>
    "#);

    Ok(response)
}
```

**Output**

```
   Compiling gcd-online v0.1.0 (~/oreilly-programming-rust-book-examples/chapter-1/gcd-online)                                                          
error[E0277]: the trait bound `mime::Mime: iron::modifier::Modifier<iron::Response>` is not satisfied                                                                           
  --> src/main.rs:17:14                                                                                                                                                         
   |                                                                                                                                                                            
17 |     response.set_mut(mime::TEXT_HTML_UTF_8);                                                                                                                               
   |              ^^^^^^^ the trait `iron::modifier::Modifier<iron::Response>` is not implemented for `mime::Mime`
```

My **Cargo.toml** uses latest version of dependencies, however book author uses following versions

```
[dependencies]
iron = "0.5.1"
mime = "0.2.3"
router = "0.5.1"
urlencoded = "0.5.0"
```

and as part of which author used following code

```
#[macro_use] extern crate mime;

fn get_form(_request: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let mut response = Response::new();

    response.set_mut(mime!(Text/Html; Charset=Utf8));

    Ok(response)
}
```

I think the difference in versions is what is causing the compilation error.

I tried to go through the docs of the [iron](https://docs.rs/iron/0.6.0/iron/) and [mime](https://docs.rs/crate/mime/0.3.12) crates but I couldn't figure out how to get past this error.

Comment: An update: I switched `mime` to `0.2.3` and used the macro `mime!` as shown above under **Note** and the code compiled successfully. So I guess there is some compatibility issue between `iron 0.6.0` and `mime 0.3.12`.

Answer (score 3):

As you've noticed, newest versions of *mime* and *iron* are not compatible with the example code from the book. The [issue was raised on the official book's repository](https://github.com/ProgrammingRust/examples/issues/2).

You could use the old *mime* crate, but in the long run it would be best to use *mime* from the *iron* crate [as explained in the docs](https://insanitybit.github.io/Cricket/iron/headers/struct.ContentType.html).

For *iron* 0.6.0 you can replace the faulty line:

```
response.set_mut(mime::TEXT_HTML_UTF_8);
```

or

```
response.set_mut(mime!(Text/Html; Charset=Utf8));
```

with one of the following:

```
response.headers.set(iron::headers::ContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8".parse::<iron::mime::Mime>().unwrap()));
```

or

```
response.headers.set(iron::headers::ContentType(
    iron::mime::Mime(
        iron::mime::TopLevel::Text,
        iron::mime::SubLevel::Html,
            vec![(iron::mime::Attr::Charset, iron::mime::Value::Utf8)])
    )
);
```

Comment: That looks too much to set just a mime type. I hope the crate authors resolves the compatibility issue and also facilitate a concise way to do this like it is the case with older version. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure it's too much, you can even squash it to: `response.set_mut("text/html; charset=utf-8".parse::<Mime>().unwrap());`. I suppose it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs Yes, you can use it. Just verified. But you need to use `iron::mime::Mime`, if not, you get an error message **error[E0412]: cannot find type Mime in this scope**. Also whole line should be `response.set_mut("text/html; charset=utf-8".parse::<iron::mime::Mime>().unwrap());`.